# Graphic Slate( graphic tablet)

Tags: raspbian, display, image

Can I connect a [Genee graphics slate](https://www.geneeworld.com/product/genee-slate-wireless-graphic-tablet/) to a Raspberry Pi?[image: monitor and a Genee graphic slate]

Comment: How does it connect to a normal PC (USB I am assuming)? Does it need or have a driver for the PI?

Answer (score 1):

Barring a third party driver being made available, you will not be able to use this tablet (or the associated screen) with a Raspberry Pi. The manufacturer [provides drivers](https://www.geneeworld.com/software-support/) for Windows and Mac but not Linux, which is the one you'll need.

Comment: +1. Not only the OP will need a driver for Linux (which may appear one day considering there is a Mac driver), he will need it for ARM architecture which almost certainly won't happen.

Comment: It doesn't have to be that bad. Most likely this is a USB HID device and works with one of the existing tablet drivers or need minor tweaking only. But one had to have some programming and debugging skills to find out which.